# CSS : Identical buttons

Tags: css

I'm trying to create buttons that are horizontally next to each other but they have to be the same size. I'm kind of new to HTML but know the basics etc, I use an unordered list within a navigation in my HTML file. Here's the CSS code:

```
.bannerArea nav ul li{
    list-style:none;    
    display:inline;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color:#0C0C0C;
    opacity:0.7;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2cQr9/

Also how do I put the block of popular projects next to the News block?

Comment: create http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the "display:inline" to

```
display:inline-block;
```

and adding something like

```
width: 100px;
```

Comment: I tried but it puts the buttons vertical, I want them horizontaly next to eachother.